# What is the most efficient way to subtract one list from another?

Tags: csv, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to subtract List_1 (50k lines) from List_2 (100k lines) , when an item in List_1 is an exact match for an item in List_2. I am using `grep`, specifically:

`grep -v -f List_1.csv List_2.csv > Magic_List.csv`

I know this is not the most efficient way to do this, but what is? `sed`? `awk`? `comm`? SQL? How might I accomplish this in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: In your csv, are you removing any item on any row? or is compared row by row?

Comment: Depends on exactly how you define "subtract" for lists.  Treat the lists as sets?  Or can the lists contain duplicates and is order relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the most efficient ways IMHO, you need to add *-F* though:

```
grep -Fvf List_1.csv List_2.csv > Magic_List.csv
```

Comment: Why would this save time? (I'm not arguing with you, I'm curious. :) )

Comment: Because it doesn't search for regular expressions, but only for fixed strings, it's called also fast grep ...

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. What kind of speed increase can I expect? Any idea?

Comment: Too much :) `% print -l {1..5000} > file[12]` `print -l {5000..10000} >> file2` `% time grep -Fvf file1 file2 >&-
grep -Fvf file1 file2 >&-  0.02s user 0.01s system 77% cpu 0.041 total` `% time grep -vf file1 file2 >&-
grep -vf file1 file2 >&-  0.35s user 0.06s system 97% cpu 0.421 total`

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way is to use a trie data structure or a hash function for the 2nd list and for each item in the first list search in your trie.

Comment: I'm not 100% with you here. How might I do that?

Comment: A trie is a powerful data structure. In general it is possible to build all the math on just some rules and a hierarchical data structure and also substraction.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to benchmark it to find the most efficient method. This is, however, what `comm` is for, so I'd guess it would be a pretty tool.

```
comm -13 List_1.csv List_2.csv > Magic_List.csv
```

Comment: It should be noted though, that comm operates on sorted input: `comm - compare two sorted files line by line`.